# Apache ServiceMix 7.0.0.M2 - Accessing Web Console Remotely

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, apache-servicemix

Anyone know what the trick is to enable the web console on Apache ServiceMix to allow remote connections?

URLs like "http://localhost:8181/system/console" are kind of useless on Amazon EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and update [iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604840/how-to-configure-direct-http-access-to-ec2-instance) of your EC2 instance to accept http connections.