# How can I connect to my ubuntu server via http?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I have started using AWS t2.micro virtual machine. I installed apache2 and curl on it. If I type curl localhost on the ubuntu machine, it gives me the correct page. How do I now connect to the ubuntu machine with http from windows and fetch the same page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure direct http access to EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604840/how-to-configure-direct-http-access-to-ec2-instance)

Comment: Have you opened port 80 on your EC2 instance's Security Group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by doing this in AWS:

- Open **EC 2 Dashboard**
- Open **Instances**
- Click the instance I want to connect to

  - Scroll down to description and look at "Security Groups"

    - Look at the name of security group, mine was "launch-wizard 3"
- On the sidebar, go to **Network & Security** > **Security Groups**
- Find security group name (for me it was launch-wizard3), click on it and look down below where it says **inbound**, click on it.
- Click **edit**
- **add rule**
- Type: HTTP, Source: anywhere
- **Save**
- Connect to your public ip and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the security group of that instance(virtual machine) adding to inbound rules: port `80`, Protocol `tcp` and source (IP to accept connection from) either the **static** IP address of the windows computer or `0.0.0.0/0` (any IP address).